# How to update VAST tag after its call?

Tags: python, video, vast

I want my VAST to play a video generated on the fly: I have Python code generating custom video in about 1s, then putting it online & returning its URL.

Is it possible that:

- the ad server calls my VAST tag
- VAST tag launches the Python method
- it waits 1s for the video to be generated, then automatically updates its `MediaFile` field with the video URL
- ad server plays the video ?

There must be some VAST feature allowing to wrap code, update itself, adding a delay... Ad Pods are a nice feature but unfortunately I think they're only playable for in-stream solutions (i.e. inside a video player).

Sorry for the lack of knowledge here!
Thanks

Comment: Any special reason to generate the video client-sided? It would be much better to do the dynamic part server-sided and only serve the VAST ad as the player should play it.

Comment: Hi @Zero2 we already generate the video server-sided: once it's done, we update the VAST with the video path, for the ad server.

Comment: You don't need "something" to update the `MediaFile` field, but place/save the video under a resource send within the `MediaFile` tag. Configure the server to wait up to 2 seconds if the file not exists, before sending a 404. For the player it will just look like a damn slow response :)

Comment: Thanks @zyexal ;) We've tried your solution. With our own server, it's OK; but the ad server cannot be told to wait extra time.

Comment: 1) generate VAST with custom video resource URL 2) send VAST and start generating video under that resource 3) wait for request to that resource 4.1)  if video is ready send it 4.2) if not tell the server to wait for resource up to 2sec (redirect might be a solution too) 4.3) 404 if resource doesn't exists - there should be no problem except for open ports. If so, you might want to try vert.x, akka or something as video cdn

Comment: @zyexal Thanks a lot. Will keep you informed.